# Function in a function testing prog

Tags: haskell

I have a question about a selecting process.
I want to make a program where you type in a operation, a value and a list.

For example: `programName (>) 4 [1,2,4,2,5]`, and it should return: `[1,2,3]`.

I know how to make a program that make the function take takes whats equal in a list and make a new list like this:

```
programEqual :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
programEqual e [] = []
programEqual e (x:xs) = if (e == x) then e : takeEqual e xs else takeEqual e xs
```

I also understand that that you need two functions for this, but I can't understand how I should get the `(tester)` stuff in there.

Comment: `programName (>) 4 [1,2,4,2,5]`, and it should return: `[1,2,3]`. Where's that `3` coming from?

Comment: my bad, what i ment was: [1,2,2]

Comment: So what you want is essentially `filter`? `filter (< 4) [1, 2, 4, 2, 5] == [1,2,2]`

Comment: but i want the (<) operation to be seperatly from the number like in my example.

Comment: Soooo.... `filter2 op x = filter (op x)` and then `filter2 (<) 4 [1,2,4,2,5] == [1,2,2]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt your previous program by adding a function argument. Here's a hint:

```
programEqual :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
programEqual f e [] = []
programEqual f e (x:xs) = if ....
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it this far but it's the if statement Im mostly confused with could you give me some more help please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want to implement that the easiest way possible

Just use `filter`:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

filter (< 4) [1, 2, 4, 2, 5] == [1, 2, 2]
```

If you want to pass the operator and the operand separately:

```
filter' op x = filter (op x)
```

and then

```
filter' (<) 4 [1,2,4,2,5] == [1,2,2]
```

---

#### If you want to tinker

There's a very useful function defined in `Data.List`:

```
takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Its signature should be rather helpful for you.

---

Here's a hint:

```
(>)   :: Int -> Int -> Bool     -- simplified from Eq a => ..
(> 4) ::        Int -> Bool
```

Comment: have in mind that i alredy have the "takeEqual". I want my new part to do:


select :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]


select f e [] = []


select f e (x:xs) = if (f == (==) something) then e : takeEqual e xs else takeEqual e xs


else if ( f == (>) something) then e : takeWhile  e xs else.... etc


I'm used to Java so Haskell is very confusing to me. :S

Comment: @KalleJohansson can you add the definition of `takeEqual` to your queston?

Comment: Do I have to define the (<) function or is it not allredy defined in haskell :S

Comment: @KalleJohansson It is already defined as a part of `Ord`. Did you notice my previous comment?